# lose less numbers when making a string from table SQL Server

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table with doubles like `0.681672875510799`

so for example a dummy table:

```
a1      a2
-------------------------
1      0.681672875510799
NULL    1
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
```

When I do

```
DECLARE @CommaString nvarchar(max)
SET @CommaString = ''
SELECT @CommaString = 
STUFF(
(SELECT  ',' + CAST([col] AS VARCHAR) FROM (
 SELECT [a1] AS col FROM [ta] UNION ALL 
 SELECT [a2] AS col FROM [ta] 
) alldata FOR XML PATH('')  )  ,   1  ,   1  ,  '' )
PRINT @CommaString;
```

This prints:

```
1,0.681673,1
```

so I am losing several decimals, which are also important, How do I modify the code to get
`1,0.681672875510799,1` instead of `1,0.681673,1`?

Comment: please (always) post the table schema definition

Comment: the table has only  float datatypes and is like in the example (can have NULLs)

Comment: Changing `CAST([col] AS VARCHAR)` to just `[col]` (so not `CAST`ing it) work.  Admittedly, I'm not sure why =/  Or, at least, let's you SELECT the whole decimal.  It might break the rest of the query.

Comment: I am getting `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3
Error converting data type varchar to float.
` maybe I did something wrong... can you post your answer?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  You have to CAST it to VARCHAR (as you have) in order to do string concatenation.  Just a minute

Comment: What happens when you `SELECT CAST([a2] AS VARCHAR)`?

Comment: I get the same rsult 0.681672875510799 - 0.681673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner query:

```
SELECT  ',' + CAST([col] AS VARCHAR) 
FROM (
  SELECT [a1] AS col FROM [ta] 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT CAST([a2] AS DECIMAL(18,15)) AS col FROM [ta]
```

Casting the FLOAT to a DECIMAL works for me (SQL Server 2008 R2).  You may have to tweak the (18,15) to work with your data.

Just noticed one more thing that works (and probably more consistently):

```
SELECT  ',' + CONVERT(varchar(max), col, 128)
FROM (
  SELECT [a1] AS col FROM [ta] 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT [a2] AS col FROM [ta]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are casting to varchar without specifying the size, you need to do `CAST([col] AS VARCHAR(max)`

```
DECLARE @CommaString nvarchar(max)
SET @CommaString = ''
SELECT @CommaString = 
STUFF(
(SELECT  ',' + cast(CAST( [col] as decimal(22,19)) as varchar(30)) FROM (
 SELECT [a1] AS col FROM [#ta] UNION ALL 
 SELECT [a2] AS col FROM [#ta] 
) alldata FOR XML PATH('')  )  ,   1  ,   1  ,  '' )
PRINT @CommaString;
```

The problem is that you will get a lot of zeroes as decimals even for the integer values. You probably need to do some other transformation if you care about that.

**EDIT:** Including my table definition:

```
create table #ta 
(
   a1 int,
  a2 float
)
```

**EDIT:** changed my table definition again from decimal to float for column b and added double casting in my query.

It now produces: `1.0000000000000000000,1.0000000000000000000,0.6816728755107990500`

Comment: mmm I tried it, but it keeps rounding it  `0.681672875510799` to `0.681673`

Comment: Hmm.  That's not working for me (that's what I thought at first as well)

Comment: It worked for me, but maybe because I defined my data type for column b to be decimal(22,19). When I run your sql statement I get: 1.0000000000000000000,1.0000000000000000000,0.6816728755107990000

Comment: Ah, that's probably your problem.  Try again defining a2 as float, I think you'll see what we're seeing.

Comment: @jadarnel27 yes, I see the issue but then double casting, first to decimal(22,19) and then to varchar does work: cast(CAST( [col] as decimal(22,19)) as varchar(30))

Comment: Right, that's what I noticed in my answer.  `CAST`ing `a2` to `DECIMAL` when it's selected (in the innermost query), then doing the `CAST` to `VARCHAR` at the next level works.